# Are references important in the Netherlands?

Tags: references, netherlands

I am considering moving to the Netherlands and need to find a job.

How important is it with references when looking for qualified (IT) positions in the Netherlands? I have good local references but they generally don't speak English and I don't want to make them feel uncomfortable or embarrass them.

Comment: Honesty always wins! Mention you have your good local references and also mention they don't speak very good English! They might want to email them instead of calling, or might just not contact them at all. Simples!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not very.

I've have had several jobs in the Netherlands over the past 30 years, and for only one, they asked for references. And only after the first round of interviews. And I have provided a references for someone else only once as well.

Now, this is just personal experience, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have the same experience in the Netherlands: several jobs and not once they asked references.

Comment: Same, one asked for references but didn’t contact them in the end.

Comment: This is my experience too. That said, some companies do want to verify recent work history (last 3-4 years or something like that), but there a confirmation that person X worked for company Y from date1 to date2 is usually considered sufficient.